# Can you put an Aura on a creature after Sludge Monster's effect?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I enchant a creature with an aura *after* [Sludge Monster](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sludge%20Monster) puts a counter on it, and makes it a 2/2 with no abilities, will the aura work? The rules specifically say the aura wouldn't work if it was on the creature before-hand. I'm trying to see if I can give it an ability, such as flying, after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Any ability modification after the Sludge Monster *enters the battlefield* will apply on top of its effect that makes a creature a 2/2 with no abilities. It doesn't matter when the counter is added.**

When two effects make the same kind of modification to an object's characteristics (changing its abilities, in this case), they are by default applied in timestamp order. This order is generally what you would intuitively expect: you apply effects that were created earlier, and then effects that were created later. In this particular case, the effect comes from Sludge Monster's second ability, which is a static ability, so its timestamp is determined by [rule 613.7a](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Layer):

> A continuous effect generated by a static ability has the same timestamp as the object the static ability is on, or the timestamp of the effect that created the ability, whichever is later. [...]

Any effect that adds abilities that is created after the Sludge Monster enters the battlefield applies after the abilities are removed, so the creature will keep those abilities.